# Xquartz and MacOS Sierra

Tags: x11, macos-sierra, xquartz

I am facing issue to make some of my applications that run under XQuartz work. This happened after I have updated my OS to Sierra version. I didn't have these issues with the previous OS versions.
when I try to Open any of my application like Winskin, and other applications in my field. I get the error message that is titled **The application X11 could not be opened**. and follows with An error occurred while starting the X11 server: "Failed to activate core devices." this for Winskin. in another application, ADF, ADF I got "An error occurred while starting the X11 server: "Unrecognized option: -iglx".
I looked it up online, I haven't find a solution yet. Any advice would be appreciated. 
Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

The problem is likely that the remote machine wants to use "Indirect GLX", and that is disabled on your Mac.  From this web page:  https://www.visitusers.org/index.php?title=Re-enabling_INdirect_glx_on_your_X_server, the instructions for MacOS are to run this in your terminal:

```
defaults write org.macosforge.xquartz.X11 enable_iglx -bool true
```

You have to restart XQuartz after this, and things should work again.

Do note however, that the reason IGLX is normally disabled is that it's a likely security risk:  make sure you trust the application that's running remotely if you choose to do this.  See this commit to `xorg` for some discussion: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/commit/d0da0e9c3bb8fe0cd4879ecb24d21715bfaa209b.