# macos-sierra xquartz installation successful but app will not run

Tags: macos, xquartz

I have installed the latest version of Xquartz from www.xquartz.org and the installer says it was successful. However, it will not run and I have to force quit it. I also tried a much older version of x11 via MacPorts and it worked, but is not compatible with X2go client, which is how I'd prefer to use it. Apple support will not assist.

I didn't find an answer yet, here or on xquartz site. [Xquartz and MacOS Sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42009559/xquartz-and-macos-sierra) has a similar question but no answer.